# Find all integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3 + y^3 +1 = 6xy$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

> $x^3 + y^3 +1 = 6xy \quad $ for $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

Can you give me a **hint** how to solve this problem, because I can come up with a solution.

Comment: This is an elliptic curve; if you could find its rank, that might help.

Comment: Well, if you share your thoughts and attempts with us, we can tell you if they are correct or not.

Comment: You mean "so that I can come up with a solution" or "because I cannot come up with a solution"

Comment: @KennyLau First one, apparently. As i said, I only need a hint.

Comment: You really need to specify whether $x,y$ can be negative integers. May make a huge difference (or not) for the answer, but most certainly it will make a huge difference for the answer (see asdf's post)! As Lord Shark pointed out, this is really about elliptic curves. But it sounds like you didn't encounter them in such a context. So, you also need to add context such as: where did you encounter this question? What related results have been covered? etc.

Answer (score 3):

WLOG we can assume $x \geq y$. If $x\geq 6$ then we have
$$x^3+y^3+1>x^3\geq 6x^2\geq 6xy$$ which is a contradiction,

Hence $x \leq 5$.

Now there are just $5$ cases to check which you can check similarly.

The answer is $(x,y)\in\{(2,3);(3,2)\}$

Comment: "for $ x,y ∈ \mathbb{N}$" is said in the problem

Comment: Apologies, I read the title.

Comment: If integers, rather than positive integers are in view, it is easy to see they can't both be negative, but in this case $x=0$ needs to be considered too.